# AngularJS: Call asp.net WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webmethod

I'm pretty new to AngularJS.

**This is my HTML:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html ng-app="Resource">
<head runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="JS/controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ResourcesCtrl">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Value
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Comment
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Action
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="resource in resources">
                        <td>
                            {{resource.KeyName}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{resource.Text}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{resource.Comment}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Update</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my JS:**

```
var myModule = angular.module('Resource', []).factory('ResourceData', function($http) {
    return {
        getResources: function(prmLangId) {
            //return the promise directly.
            return $http.get('Default.aspx/GetResources', { langId: prmLangId }).
                       then(function(result) {
                           //resolve the promise as the data
                           console.log(result);
                           return result.data;
                       });
        }
    }
});

myModule.config(function($httpProvider) {

            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};

            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        });

function ResourcesCtrl($scope, ResourceData) {
    $scope.resources = ResourceData.getResources(1033);
}
```

**And this is the server method:**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string GetResources(int langId)
    {
        ResourcesManagerBL resBl = new ResourcesManagerBL(langId);
        var resources = resBl.GetResourcesForLanguage(langId);
        return Json.ToJson(resources);
    }
```

The result is many blank rows (as the number of the resources),
What I'm doing wrong, in the console the data look OK.

**The result is something like this:**

[image]

Comment: Change the parm datatype int to string

Comment: @RameshRajendran, it did not help..

Comment: If result contains html instead of json string, then the method is not correctly being hit. Try to hit the url `Default.aspx/GetResources/1033` with some tools  like fiddler or `Postman` (chrome tool) by setting appropriate headers and see if you get json result.

Comment: Can you show the result?

Comment: @Chandermani, I was able to make the call, and the data returns fine but I still present blank rows (only with the static "Update" string for each row)

Comment: We are interested in your json data, what is the format of json data. Give us a sample for that.

Comment: Why would you use a web method? Use Web API to create proper rest end point. Web methods are a very out dated method.

Answer (score 0):

web method can return the actual type (like List) , and module should be populated with result.data.d